# Why doesn’t the button show back?

Tags: html, css

I have a modal button, I hide it and then I want to show it. The button does not appear. How to show?

```css
button {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"> Modal
</button>
```

Comment: Where's your JavaScript code??

Comment: I have not Javascript code.

Comment: Than how do you hide and show the button??

Comment: with help display.(none, block)

Comment: `@media screen and (max-width: 599px) { }` must enclose *rulesets*, not declarations. A ruleset consists of  a selector **and** declarations.

Answer (score 1):

Check your media query code
*Note:- Your button will show on viewport 559px as per your code*

```css
button{display:none;}
@media screen and (max-width:599px){
button{display:block;} /*issue exits here*/
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Modal
</button>
```